# How many possible solutions are to the inequation $x_1+ ... +x_{n} \leq k$?

Tags: combinatorics

Given $\forall i, i=1....n$ | $s.t$  $x_i\in\mathbb{N}$ .

1.How many possible solutions are to the equation: $  x_1+x_2+...x_{n}\leq k$ ?

2.If $x_i\in\mathbb{Z}$?

3.If $x_i\leq i$ $ \forall i$ ?

*Note: $0\notin\mathbb{N} $

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Does $\mathbb N $ include $0$?

Comment: I Know the answers to the top 2, couldnt figure one out for the last one actually. If no one finds a solution to all 3 I will post my solution to the top 2.

Comment: The first is an application of stars and bars with a clever trick, the second is just some reasoning, and the third requires inclusion-exclusion. Notice that the number of cases depends only on the size of the index set $I \subset [n]$ chosen, so you can gain a closed formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question 3 may be interesting and here is the solution for rather arbitrary restriction $x_i\le r_i$. To satisfy the inequality
$$  x_1+x_2+...x_{n}\leq k$$
we introduce an additional dummy variable $x_0$ and count the number of solutions to the equation:
$$
x_0+x_1+\cdots+x_n=k,
$$
where $x_0$ is non-negative and the other $x_i$ are positive integer numbers.

In terms of generating functions we are looking for the coefficient at $x^k$ in the product:
$$\begin{align}
\frac1{1-x}x^n\prod_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=0}^{r_i-1}x^j
&=\frac1{1-x}x^n\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{1-x^{r_i}}{1-x}\\
&=\frac{x^n\prod_{i=1}^n(1-x^{r_i})}{(1-x)^{n+1}}\\
&=x^n\prod_{i=1}^n(1-x^{r_i})\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{-n-1}{j}(-x)^j\\
&=x^n\prod_{i=1}^n(1-x^{r_i})\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{n+j}{j}x^{j}\\
&=\sum_{\boldsymbol{\mu}}(-1)^{|\boldsymbol{\mu}|}x^{\boldsymbol{\mu}\cdot\boldsymbol{r}}
\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{n+j}{n}x^{n+j},
\end{align}$$
which is
$$
\sum_{\boldsymbol{\mu}}(-1)^{|\boldsymbol{\mu}|}\binom{k-\boldsymbol{\mu}\cdot\boldsymbol{r}}{n},\tag1
$$
where $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ are all $2^n$ binary vectors of the length $n$, $|\boldsymbol{\mu}|=\sum_{i=1}^n\mu_i$ and $\boldsymbol{r}=(r_1,r_2,\dots,r_n)$.

In (1) the equality $\binom mn=0$ is assumed for $m<n$.